# CSS moves parent of absolute children when one gets focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, absolute

I have a document set out like so.

When some websocket activity happens, the input field (id=bar, which is hidden by `overflow:hidden`) is eventually focused by my code and it shifts my entire parent element over so none of the other controls are visible. **Run the fiddle at the bottom for an example.**

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="left: 10px; top: 10px; background:red;">Test1</div>
    <div class="child" style="left: 10px; top: 52px">Test2<div>
    <input class="child" id="bar" style="left: 30px; top: 10px">Test3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('bar').focus();
}, 2000);
```

**Note: I set the delay on the timeout low. You may have to refresh the page to see it happen.**

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qa28q48o/2/

How can I prevent this from happening preferably at the CSS level, without using any javascript hacks on the element to reset its scroll.

Comment: what do you suppose to see through this keyhole: `.outer {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The container scrolls to the focused element eventhough it is overflow: hidden. So you result with no scrollbars seeing just a small junk of your content...

Possible solutions:
1. overflow: visible or overflow: scroll on outer
2. bigger dimensions for outer

Just give it a little more freedom, poor outer...

Comment: I don't want the scroll happening at all, and the container must be this fixed size, so the input will always be hidden regardless of focus. This is just how it is.

Comment: then place the input field outside the outer div. I mean really into nirvana or set it display: none

Comment: This is *a* 'solution', but in this particular setting there are many input fields which are rendered in a loop and we'd have to conditionally check if they are outside the bounds of the thing sized in a stylesheet and bring them up a dom level. Not very elegant and requires information we may not have/want (css values) in the JS code. `display:none` won't work because we still need to write into them.

Comment: how about position: fixed; left: -1000px; top: -1000px?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue aswell, took a while before i figured out what was going on :)

Anyhow, i solved it by doing a `.blur()` on the link that triggered the dialog, just before the dialog was opened.

```
if (link.hasClass('confirm')) {
    link.blur(); 
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
        ...
```